# why I get this error while starting eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have `64 bit window 7` ,

I have installed `java 6` and `java 7` (jdk and jre) in program files(86) 
and jre 7 in program files.

I cannot open eclipse, what would I do to start it?

[image]

Comment: You are probably using java 64bit with eclipse 32bit (or the other way around). Make sure you have the same bit version for both. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 64 bit Windows -

- program files(86) -> contains the 32 bit programs installed into your
  system.
- program files     -> contains the 64 bit programs or default installed into
  your system

What you need is 64 bit jdk, download it from here - [Link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

```
exe - jdk-7u60-windows-x64.exe
                      ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using 64bit version of Java and a 32 bit version of Eclipse. It's trying to find a 32bit Java version (or vice versa) and that's why it tells you that you need at least Java 1.5.. Try switching to a 64bit Eclipse and also check if your environment variables are set properly, especially `%JAVA_HOME%`.. You can do a quick check if you're using the correct Java version by running the command

```
java -version
```

from the command line.